# TextureView stretch image

Tags: android, android-camera, textureview, android-video-record

I'm using [this](https://github.com/afollestad/material-camera) library *( Download from Github then import project into my existing project )* to record to the video. Everything is working perfectly except **camera preview** while recording.

**camera preview** is vertically stretch when device is portrait
 **camera preview** is horizontally stretch when device is landscape.

Here is screenshot of vertically stretch.

[image]

Here is screenshot of horizontally stretch

[image]

Here is the **[AutoFitTextureView](https://github.com/afollestad/material-camera/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/afollestad/materialcamera/internal/AutoFitTextureView.java)** java file which use as custom TextureView.

Here is complete **[Library](https://github.com/afollestad/material-camera/tree/master/library/src/main/java/com/afollestad/materialcamera)** link of github.

Comment: and you called `setAspectRatio`? if so, with what params?

Comment: @pskink , yes i called `setAspectRatio` method inside AutoFitTextureView class with two parameter i.e. width and height , here is my code                                                   `public void setAspectRatio(int width, int height) {
    if (width < 0 || height < 0) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Size cannot be negative.");
    }
    mRatioWidth = width;
    mRatioHeight = height;
    requestLayout();
  }`